# Change save behavior in OnlyOffice desktop apps

Tags: onlyoffice

Hellо, all!

Is there a way to change behavior when saving previously opened xls or doc file?

OnlyOffice can't save to xls or doc, instead it saves to xlsX or docX and as a result there is file duplicates and confusion of who is who.

What i want is to modify through plugin or directly in code that when saving xls to xlsx the old xls file will be deleted and alert appears.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot be done through plugins but we have plans to add the advanced configuration options to one of the future versions.
Your suggestion will be discussed internally, it is already accepted as enhancement.

I would also recommend to create [a new issue](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors/issues)